# Arguments not passing through my service between controllers

Tags: angularjs, controllers

Here is my service:

```
var MyService= function () {
    var filters, charts, subscription;

    return {
        getFilters: function () {
            return this.filters;
        },
        setFilters: function (value) {
            this.filters = value;
        },
        getCharts: function () {
           return this.charts;
        },
        setCharts: function (value) {
           this.charts = value;
        },
        getSubscription: function () {
           return this.subscription;
        },
        setSubscription: function (value) {
           this.subscription = value;
        }
    };
};

angular.module('Something').factory('MyService', MyService);
```

Your typical service that can be used to pass arguments between controllers.

Controller A has a function that gets called when a user selects a link; the function sets my item in my service and uses window to redirect to another page.

```
$scope.pressedButton = function (subscription) {
   MyService.setSubscription(subscription);
   $window.location.href = 'newPage.html';
}
```

Controller B for the newPage.html should be able to read and console.log out myItem from my service however, it says it's undefined.

```
console.log(MyService.getSubscription()) == undefined.
```

Anyone know why? I've been using setters and getters but because I'm a bit limited to my routing ($window instead of ui-router or ng-router), I feel like moving to a brand new page is what's clearing out my service...

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may have the syntax of factories and services swapped.

```
myApp.factory('sample', function(){
  var obj = {
    item: ''
  }
  return {
    getItem: function () {
      return obj.item;
    },
    setItem: function (value) {
      obj.item= value;
    }
  }
}
```

vs a service

```
myApp.service('sample', function(){
  var _item = '';
  this.getItem = function () {
      return _item;
    };
  this.setItem = function (value) {
      _item = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just looked at my code and yes it is supposed to be a factory since I do use angular.module('something').factory('MyService', MyService). But it doesn't solve anything... the code still isn't being shown in a new controller.

Comment: When a factory is initiated, the values are constant, so you can't modify the  variables inside the factory anymore. My example showed an instantiated object, so you would be only changing the referenced value with my factory methods. In your example, the variables would always be undefined as initiated upon load.

If you think of a service as aJavascript

Comment: Still undefined - I'm pretty sure it's re-instantiating my factor when I call window because I'm using that service in another set of controllers and because I'm opening up a model/dialog box instead, the values pass on from one controller to another without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I personally prefer the `$factory` data model syntax, as it gives you pseudo-private variables and a single access point for all this data. This makes it easier to test your code, and less likely for it to gain malformed data.

Also, if you are going to be trying to route around like that, I would recommend ui-router.

In a seperate service from where you are doing the set/get, include `$state` and just inject that template file into your view.

But syntax wise, @alwang85 is correct. :+1:

Comment: I am using factory (I think)... yes I would love to use ui-router but the project was built before I was so trying to add in ui-router is more work than I would like. Can you explain the $state part a bit more? Give an example maybe?